# dimensions of image read using tfio.image.decode_dicom_image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imaging, medical-imaging

I read a .dcm image from my own dataset using tfio.image.decode_dicom_image following [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/dicom.ipynb) link. The shape of the read image is shown as (None,None,None,None). While displaying the image using plt.imshow, the output of np.squeeze is zero-dimensional and hence giving error in 2-d image display. Could someone please help me understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try pydicom to read .dcm data

```
from pydicom import dcmread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

read= dcmread('000000.dcm')
img=read.pixel_array
plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
```

or sometime the directiory is wrong

Comment: Thanks, I tried reading using pydicom also, but this creates a break in the tensorflow graph and I had to use py_function/numpy_function, which is giving another error "as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape." which I could not resolve. So I tried keeping pure tensorflow code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've missed is reading the file first. I was also thinking that `tfio.image.decode_dicom_image` will eliminate the need for the `tf.io.read_file`, but no.

```
     import tensorflow_io as tfio
     
     image_bytes = tf.io.read_file('dicom_00000001_000.dcm')
     
     image = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_bytes, dtype=tf.uint16)
```

Reference : https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/dicom?hl=tr